# How do I manage recurrent child UIViewControllers?

Tags: swift3, childviewcontroller

Scenario:

1. I instantiate a UIViewController and added it to a
   containerViewController.
2. I dismiss (remove) this child
3. I select this same child to display again.

**My Concern:** I wish to create a single child UIViewController instance. 
But It appears that I would create an additional instance of the child view controller per 'case' iteration, which I do not want.

**Question:** Does Swift already handle this? 
...or must I check for the current view controller's instance prior to making it a child?

If I have to check for its existance, then I'll have to make 'viewController' global for all cases.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No Swift doesn't handle this automatically. You must check the existing child view controllers to prevent adding duplicates.

You could use code like this:

```
if let controller = parent.childViewControllers.filter { $0 is CountriesViewController }.first {
    // use existing child controller here
}
else {
    // create new child controller and add it to parent here
}
```